# Extract string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some URLs in various lengths in an Excel sheet.  For example:

www._______________________________/article1-**1328904**.aspx
www.__________________/article1-**2754304**.aspx

I have to extract the 7 digit number from the URL. I have to implement this function for 1000s of rows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it always at the end like that, before `.aspx`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the URLs end with your seven digit number followed by .aspx, you could do this.  Say the URLs are in column A, starting in row 1.  In cell B1, put:

```
=MID(A1,LEN(A1)-11,7)
```

Copy that down for all of the data rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL doesn't *always* end in ".aspx" but you *do* always want the 7 characters immediately preceding it, you can use this formula instead:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(".aspx",A1)-7,7)
```